# Question about calculating the torque of a magnet in an additive field

Tags: electromagnetism, torque

I did an experiment in the lab today where I placed a magnet in between two coiled magnets, with one coiled magnet having its south side up and north side down and the other coiled magnet with the north side up and south side down. The magnet in the middle started to rotate, which made me believe that the interaction between the magnetic fields of the coiled magnets provided the torque needed to make it move.

I was wondering how you would go about calculating the torque of this magnet. I know that $ \tau = F \cdot L$ where $L$ is the radius of a wheel and that torque can also be defined in the electromagnetic way as $K \cdot I$ where $I$ is the current and $K$ is some constant. In the following lesson, we learned that for a DC shunt motor the torque is $K I_f \cdot I_a$ where $I_f$ is the current for the field coil and $I_a$ is the current for the armature. Can someone explain the way to calculate the torque of this magnet and how  $ \tau = F \cdot L$ is equivalent to formulas like $K \cdot I$?